# How can I get a real map and write on it?

Tags: images, maps

I am in bad need to have a real map and add a route on it with some writing on it. Like the image attached. Any suggestions please 
[image]

Comment: go on google maps, download the needed part, add writing in photoshop, done

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - gald to have you here. Please take a look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community and what we're about. Please also look at [ask] and [answer] a question so that you can understand best practice in formatting your issue, and what to expect in replies. I'd also recommend a brief glance over [help/behavior] to learn what our community's behavioural expectations are. As initially written, your question is *very* unclear - one can see neither what you've tried nor where you're stuck - please refine to make clear your specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

Google maps are copyright - and so technically not legal to use.

However you could use OpenStreetMap instead. Their maps are free to use for any purpose, under an Open licence.  To keep it simple, just take a screenshot, paste into the software of your choice and add annotations.

If you want to take it a little further, depending on your level of expertise, it's also possible to download the map as an SVG. Then you could open it in a vector image editor such as Inkscape (which is free), or in Adobe Illustrator, if you have access to that software.